# is there an way to make a tuple instead of the usual way

Tags: c++, data-structures, tuples, c++17

when i tried to write this code

```
int c, b;
auto  [c,b] = make_tuple(12,14);
```

it gives me this error : `error: structured binding declaration cannot have type 'int'` then the two erros in the title so what's the wrong with the code (note : I'am using c++17)

i was expecting to create the tuple like this code line  `tuple <int ,int > t = make_tuple(4,3);`

Comment: You reused previously declared names.

Comment: If you're trying to reassign existing names, you want `std::tie(c, b) = make_tuple(12, 14);`

Comment: You only need to remove `int c, b;`. It doesn't belong there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already declared c and b as ints in the previous line, so you cannot use a structured binding declaration because that redeclares b and c.

If you want to reassign c and b to the tuple, use `std::tie(c, b) = make_tuple(12, 14);`

If you want to declare c and b using a structured binding declaration, remove the `int c, b;` declaration.